# Why so many scifi books have a one world government if this idea is considered stupid?

Tags: science-fiction-genre

There are some guys that believe that a new world order will happen, those guys are called crazy and etc.. with people saying their idea is super mega ultra stupid.

So, my question is, why something so nonsensical is so present into scifi, why so many scifi stuff assume new world order?

Comment: As it stands this question is inviting opinion and speculation, and is not a good fit for our Q&A format. Please take a look at the [What not to ask](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page for more details. If you can update your question to be more narrow and less speculative, we can get it re-opened.

Comment: As Mike said. But here is  my opinion. Because until we settle out petty differences we wont be able to rally move forward. If the money we spend for military to fight among ourselfs is spend for space travel we would get there relatively soon. In honesty we don't need one government for whole world we just need to spot fighting each other and work together to common goal. Al tho that would eventually lead to unification in one government. Anyway for space travel or any of things we see and read in Sci-Fi to happen we need to do it together, otherwise we would not get there at all.

Comment: What they said. Also, your proposition is flawed. The phrase "world government" is not synonymous with "new world order". Oh, and your question is a rant rather than a question.

Comment: If one can get the NWO stuff out of the question via an edit, might it be re-opened?  I see the germ of an OK, if not brilliant, question about the Sci Fi genre therein.

Answer (score 7):

Putting aside the subjective viewpoint that such an idea is 'stupid'. The New World Order is not the same as World Government. The New World Order conspiracy is based upon the idea of a powerful, shadowy elite who control world politics and government from 'behind the scenes' so to speak.

World government is more of an assumed natural progression in human civilization. That eventually, as space travel becomes more commonplace, we will feel more united as a planet and our provincial squabbles will become more insignificant. I cannot claim to know this for sure, but I would presume a lot of Sci Fi takes ideas about future civilization structures and organisation from the [Kardashev Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale) which defines various levels of a civilizations technological advancement based upon energy production/consumption. Looking at the criteria, it stands to reason that the higher levels would demand cooperation on at least a planetary scale to achieve. Cooperation coordinated by a central planetary authority, in other words a world government.